# S2E/Link2SD and all other apps get corrupted?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-ace, link2sd

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace powered by the official CyanogenMod. I don't know what caused this issue but it has happened twice already. Once on Link2SD, the other while using S2E.
And on both times:

1. My phone was either stuck or took a very long time at the A N D R O I D screen (upon boot, not the actual boot screen).
2. When the phone finally gets booted up, it's back to the default ADW launcher, default apps, and some user apps that my phone was able to squeeze in its internal memory.
3. On Manage Applications, all the other previously installed apps are not recognized. They can only be uninstalled.
4. Ultimately, I had to do a factory reset.

Notes:

- I used CWM v5.0.2.6 to partition my 8gb class 4 Micro SD card. I remember it being ext3 only, so I checked the option in S2E to mount it as ext4.
- I did not set the read buffer in S2E
- For what it's worth, I recently installed SuperSU

I already have a NANDROID backup and backups from Titanium Backup. But I need to know what I might have done, or whatever it is that caused this. Please help. Thank you.